# Formulario PHP responder al mail ingresado

Tags: php, html5, formularios

Estoy creando un formulario PHP y la idea es que al poner "responder" desde la bandeja de entrada, figure el mail que se ha ingresado en el formulario para responderle directamente al usuario.

Les dejo el código del formulario:

```js
<?php
$nombre = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$tel = isset($_POST['tel']) ? $_POST['tel'] : '';
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$casadx = isset($_POST['casadx']) ? $_POST['casadx'] : '';
$namecasadx = isset($_POST['namecasadx']) ? $_POST['namecasadx'] : '';
$hijos = isset($_POST['hijos']) ? $_POST['hijos'] : '';
$namehijos = isset($_POST['namehijos']) ? $_POST['namehijos'] : '';
$age = isset($_POST['age']) ? $_POST['age'] : '';
$gender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender'] : '';

$to      = 'carla.paludetto@kickads.mobi';
$subject = 'Cotización Prevem';
$message = " Se ha recibido un nuevo contacto desde la web, con los siguientes datos:<br/>
<b>Nombre:</b> $nombre<br/>
<b>Teléfono:</b> $tel<br/>
<b>E-Mail:</b> $email<br/>
<b>Cónyuge:</b> $casadx<br/>
<b>Nombre del cónyuge:</b> $namecasadx<br/>
<b>Hijos:</b> $hijos<br/>
<b>Nombre:</b> $namehijos<br/>
<b>Edad:</b> $age<br/>
<b>Género:</b> $gender 
";

$headers = 'From: carla.paludetto@kickads.mobi' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: carla.paludetto@kickads.mobi' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
header('Location: thankyou.html');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: @Alfabravo mi pregunta es: qué debería poner en `$headers` para poder responder al mail ingresado en el formulario? O sea responder al `$email`

Comment: $email aqui guardas el correo? si es asi => `mail($mail,$sunject...)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
<?php
$nombre = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$tel = isset($_POST['tel']) ? $_POST['tel'] : '';
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$casadx = isset($_POST['casadx']) ? $_POST['casadx'] : '';
$namecasadx = isset($_POST['namecasadx']) ? $_POST['namecasadx'] : '';
$hijos = isset($_POST['hijos']) ? $_POST['hijos'] : '';
$namehijos = isset($_POST['namehijos']) ? $_POST['namehijos'] : '';
$age = isset($_POST['age']) ? $_POST['age'] : '';
$gender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender'] : '';

$to      = $email ;
$subject = 'Cotización Prevem';
$message = " Se ha recibido un nuevo contacto desde la web, con los siguientes datos:<br/>
<b>Nombre:</b> $nombre<br/>
<b>Teléfono:</b> $tel<br/>
<b>E-Mail:</b> $email<br/>
<b>Cónyuge:</b> $casadx<br/>
<b>Nombre del cónyuge:</b> $namecasadx<br/>
<b>Hijos:</b> $hijos<br/>
<b>Nombre:</b> $namehijos<br/>
<b>Edad:</b> $age<br/>
<b>Género:</b> $gender 
";

$headers = 'From: carla.paludetto@kickads.mobi' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: carla.paludetto@kickads.mobi' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
header('Location: thankyou.html');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Sólo copiaste el código en la pregunta del OP, te sugiero elimines la respuesta porque para eso es este apartado para aportar solución a la interrogante que solicita el OP.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he solucionado!
En la parte inferior del código, reemplacé el correo por la variable, y de esta variable, puedo contestar directamente al mail que el usuario ingresó en el formulario.

```js
$headers = 'From: carla.paludetto@kickads.mobi' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email. "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
header('Location: thankyou.html');
exit;
```